# How can I create a new window object without iframes?

Tags: javascript

How can I make a new `Window` object, `myWindow`, that is independent to `window` (so modifying e.g. `myWindow.Array.prototype` does not effect `window.Array.prototype`), **without** creating an `<iframe>`?

At the moment I'm doing it as follows

```
function newWindow(){
    var myFrame = document.createElement('iframe'), myWindow = undefined;
    myFrame.style.display = 'none';
    myFrame.src = 'javascript:undefined;';
    document.body.appendChild(myFrame);
    myWindow = myFrame.contentWindow;
    document.body.removeChild(myFrame);
    return myWindow;
}
```

Ultimately, I'd like to make my own copies of core object types and prototype them.

Comment: Related article: [How ECMAScript 5 still does not allow to subclass array](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emm... you can't do that. Well... you may call `window.open`, but it will open a new window. And... why do you need that at all? It looks like you are on wrong way.

Comment: Because you can't subclass some JavaScript objects without them breaking, e.g. again using `Array`, if you do `var myArr = function(){}; myArr.prototype = [];`, you end up with an almost-array that breaks for `.length`

Comment: @shhac - I understand about prototype. But it is not clear why do you need a new window. Well... I can't help with prototypes as still had no chance/need to play with that. But anyway. The only ways to create new window - iframe or window.open

Comment: the `window` object is the parent of all "global variables" you have access to, making a new means new copies of all of it's children, but you can't simply construct it because it throws `TypeError: Illegal constructor`.

Comment: `(myWindow = window.open('javascript:undefined;')).close();` does make `myWindow` a `Window` object _(assuming not popup-blocked)_ and doesn't require an `<iframe>` so although this isn't quite what I wanted I suppose it does answer the question.

Comment: Or not destroy.. at least with iFrame that does not happen in chrome. I guess because garbage collector has a live reference to it...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing, a better approach may be to create a normal array, then augment that one particular array instance with the features you need.

```
function augmentArray(a) {
  a.purgeAll = function() {a.length = 0;};
}

var myList = [1, 2, 3];
augmentArray(myList);
myList.purgeAll();
```

Comment: +1, Thanks, I may have to take this path, but I'll hope to find a different way that lets me make the data type I want, this is the closest for now and I can imagine this using up lots of memory if I make many "augmented" arrays. However it doesn't answer question about `window` objects so can't choose it as right over the other answer which actually does, sorry.